# Caching controller action in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, caching, controller, cakephp-2.0

I need one of my controller action to be cached.
I added "`Cache`" to my $`helpers` variable.
And my action is like this:

```
  public function myAction($name) {
   $this->cacheAction = '10 minutes';
   //some code
  }
```

I run this action, then added one line of `echo`. And run action again.
But the result became dfferent, although action was cached.
How can I debug this issue?

I checked [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/cache.html#cachehelper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment `Configure::write('Cache.check', true);` in `app/Config/core.php`

Also I'm not sure if doing it in the action itself will work. If it doesn't add this instead to your controller as a class var.

```
public $cacheAction = array(
    'myAction' => '10 minutes',
);
```

Comment: At first call this works but I still have some issues. Do you know that where the action results are cached? I couldn't find any in "app/tmp/cache"

Comment: Hmm, I suppose I'm missing something. I have actionA. While working, actionA calls "actionB/parameter1", then actionA parses that output and pass data to view. When I add "actionB" to "$cacheAction" variable, cakePHP caches whole actionA page and saves it to cache/views folder. So when actionA calls "actionB/parameter2" same output is shown. Because cakephp looks to cache folder and finds "actionA.php" and loads it.  Is it not possible to cache in this way? Else I will use "elements". I don't prefer to use it because I must use requestAction in that case. Thank you

Comment: Want to start a new question for this showing the code in your controller? I'm not sure what you're doing.

Comment: I'd be better open another question. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511659/cakephp-caching-an-action-that-calls-another-action